# Switching between windows in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

First I have open main window then through that I have another window called order .Now I have to make a button that get to the main window again

```
def back():
    wn.destroy()
    import purchase
Button(text="Back",width='30',height='5',command=back,fg='black',bg='green',bd='5',font=(40),command=back).place(x='100',y='600')
```

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to fix the formatting errors and make sure you've provided a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the button start a function to open the window.

Ex.

```
def OpenNewWindow:
    newWindow = TopLevel(master)

B1 = tk.Button(text="example", command = OpenNewWindow
B1.pack()
```

Treat it like a normal window: geometry, title, etc.

but remember one thing:
**KEEP THE TOPLEVEL IN THE MAIN LOOP**

Comment: Also, you can add destroy command into that function to automate it more

Comment: What does "KEEP THE TOPLEVEL IN THE MAIN LOOP" mean? Widgets aren't "in" the mainloop. `mainloop` is simply a function, it's not a container for things.

Comment: Keep the toplevel function within the main windows mainloop function or it won't work, @BryanOakley

Comment: I still don't know what you mean. If `mainloop` is running, every window you create will be  managed by it, there's nothing extra you need to do.

Comment: Eaxactly -- I've seen people try to make the new window into it's own loop....

Comment: But... how? You can't "make a window into its own loop".  A window isn't a loop and isn't in a loop. Is what you're trying to say is that you shouldn't call `mainloop` a second time after creating a `Toplevel`? The words you're choosing are very unconventional and hard to understand.

Comment: Yes, people do things such as that thinking it will work -- it doesn't, in short.

Comment: Calling `mainloop` a second time works -- the window will work just fine. It has side effects that people often aren't aware of, but it definitely works.